# change popover to hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Address.initialize();
    Note.initializeIndex();
    Child.initializeEditBillPayer();
    AuditLog.Initialise();
    if ($(".aged-debetors").length !==0) {
        // set the contant of the popover when document is loaded
        $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover();
        $('.aged-debetors-label').attr("data-content", $(".aged-debetors").html());
    }
});


<span class="label label-info aged-debetors-label" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="auto right" data-html="true" data-content="" data-original-title="" title="">
    Current Balance: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.TotalUnpaidAmount)
</span>
```

Comment: It would be better if you can explain what is happening, what do you want to achieve rather than a small title and some pasted code.

Comment: currently when i click on Current Balance button type then a popup is opening but i want when cursor over the button then it happen

Answer (score 0):

You can just trigger popover on `hover`, instead of default `click` trigger like:

```
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({ trigger: 'hover' });
```

Comment: still the same after using  $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({ trigger: 'hover' });

Comment: Please do mark the [answer as accepted](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235) to help other users too.